# How does China defy GSP or quota system?

Tags: european-union, china, trade, north-america

- [Preferential Tariff (Export)](http://www.bangladeshcustoms.gov.bd/trade_info/preferential_center_ex)
- [Generalised Scheme of Preferences (GSP)](https://ec.europa.eu/trade/policy/countries-and-regions/development/generalised-scheme-of-preferences/)

Some low to middle-income countries enjoy either GSP/GSP+ or quota system when they export their goods to the EU or North America.

China doesn't have such privilege. Despite that China continues to export at a competitive price. How can they do that?

Comment: There seem to be two questions here. One on China (presumably they export at a competitive price by economies of scale, significant investment in technology to improve productivity, and driving down costs in the usual ways.  The other is why GSP exists for other countries: and this is to drive growth, leading to better lives for the people and a more stable, peaceful world order.  Those countries haven't had the significant investment in technology to improve productivity. All this seems rather obvious.

Comment: @JamesK if all of this is rather obvious, then you should answer. If there are two questions here, you should vote to close :)

Comment: I suspect that the OP has a different question in mind. I'd like to clarify before writing an answer.